# C#/WP7 Json.net parsing to list

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7

I have problem with parsing JSON to list in C#. I'm using Json.net to parse json.  My problem is that I get error "Error converting value "high" to type". Please help me.

My json:

```
{"sold":{"high":40.64625,"low":35.02,"avg":37.929384985,"buy":40.28,"sell":40.3}}
```

My code:

```
public class sold
{
    public string high { get; set; }
    public string low { get; set; }
    public string avg { get; set; }
    public string buy { get; set; }
    public string sell { get; set; }

}

   void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        JObject something = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
        IList<JToken> results = something["sold"].Children().ToList();
        IList<sold> searchResults = new List<sold>();
        foreach (JToken result in results)
            {
sold searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<sold>(result.ToString());
searchResults.Add(searchResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property high is type of double, you can try with this implementation of your class **sold**

```
public class sold
{
public double high { get; set; }
public double low { get; set; }
public double avg { get; set; }
public double buy { get; set; }
public double sell { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Now I get different error "Error converting value "high" to type 'My_app.sold'. Path '', line 1, position 6." Can you help with it?

Comment: Try : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<sold>(something["sold"].ToString());

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a wrapper class for the array of sold items and deserialize the entire array in one call. I have not tried this with json.net, but it works fine with the DataContractJsonSerializer.

```
public class SoldItemList
{
     public SoldItem[] sold { get;set; }
}
public class SoldItem
{
    public double high { get; set; }
    public double low { get; set; }
    public double avg { get; set; }
    public double buy { get; set; }
    public double sell { get; set; }
}
```